# Get applicationDidFinishLaunching call in a View Controller. Parse not initialized yet

Tags: swift, parse-platform, appdelegate

I am trying to load data from Parse in my *Initial* *View* *Controller*. The issue is that Parse is initialized in my `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching` so I need to wait until it is called before I attempt to load the data from Parse. What is the best way to get this notification in my view controller? Or would it be better to get the data in my `AppDelegate`?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an observer for the UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification inside your view controller viewDidLoad method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFinishLaunchingNotification), name: UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil)
```

Add your method to the view controller

```
@objc func didFinishLaunchingNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Freakin' perfect. I can't believe I didn't find that in my research. Thanks boss!

Comment: How can we check when key (UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location ) is available or not ?@justColbs