# Select index greater than 3 for UITabBarController at app launch not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

At app launch, I have UITabBarController as the root view controller. For this tab bar, I have total 7 ViewControllers. Inside `AppDelegate.swift` in method `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, if I do following, it works properly:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2

        return true
    }
```

This works perfectly and the third item in the tab bar is selected when the application is launched.

But, when I want to select any item which has gone under the more navigation controller (which means any index beyond 3), the `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 5` simply does not work. The mentioned statement does work at any part after the app launch is complete, i.e., if I do `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 5` inside the `viewDidAppear` of first ViewController, it works; but it doesn't work at the time of app launch,i.e., in `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. The tab bar selected item remains to default after the launch happens. What is the way I can change the selected index beyond 3 (which goes under `moreNavigationController`) at the app launch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33375674/2303865

Comment: @Leo Dabus, I want to handle deep link of push notification on application launch. So if my app in not running and push notification is received, I click on push notification. At this point `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is triggered, but first view controller is not still loaded so how will my observer work at this point as the view controller instance is not available to observe?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it is not working :(

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35080095/2303865

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
        self.tabBarController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        return true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321467) answer worked for me you can create an Inspectable var in your tabBarController class and specify the index number in storyboard.